# VBA extend rows with formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel macro, which opens up a template file and saves it under a different name once everything is done.

My VBA loads (Sub Loading) some data from the database to the INPUT sheet. There is another sheet, which uses hlookup table5 to find rows in the INPUT sheet and do some calculations.

I need to extend this Table5 and have the same number of rows as in the INPUT sheet, but it's not working. Do you have any idea how can I achieve that?

```
    StrSQL = "select * from mytable"
    Set targetSh = owb.Sheets("INPUT")
    Call Loading(targetSh, StrSQL)

    Last = targetSh.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("Table5").Offset(14, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it using this:

```
Sub RowsAction(ByRef targetSh As Worksheet, resizeSh As Worksheet, tablename 
As String)
Dim i, iLastRow As Integer, oLastRow As ListRow, srcRow As Range

Last = targetSh.Range("A1", targetSh.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)).count - 2

For i = 1 To Last
Set srcRow = resizeSh.ListObjects(tablename).ListRows(i).Range
Set oLastRow = resizeSh.ListObjects(tablename).ListRows.Add
srcRow.Copy
oLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make sure that you have inserted enough rows, that the table is in total with 20:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim listObj As ListObject
    Set listObj = Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table5")

    With listObj
        .Resize listObj.Range.Resize(20)
    End With

End Sub
```

And if you want to insert `20` rows to the rows that the table already has, then first the rows should be saved to a variable `rowsTotal`. Then, the inserted rows should be equal to `rowsTotal+20`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim listObj     As ListObject
    Dim rowsTotal   As Long

    Set listObj = Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table5")
    rowsTotal = listObj.Range.Rows.Count

    With listObj
        .Resize listObj.Range.Resize(rowsTotal + 20)
    End With

End Sub
```

Concerning the insertion of the formulas, you should not worry about it. Excel writes automatically the formula from the previous row on every newly inserted row.

Comment: Thank you. Actually it's not the fixed number of rows, but it should correspond to the number of rows in the input sheet.

Comment: @shafac14 - then you can write `rowsTotal*2` in the `Resize()`.

Comment: @shafac14 - this is strange. Are you sire that the `listObj` is on the correct worksheet?

Comment: This Macro should open another excel file and find a sheet there by name and the table within. It should resize the table according to number of rows in the input sheet of the file it just opened and save it. The Macro excel file is separate and it will stay open.